# Compiling Python 3.6: Can I delete src folder after make install?

Tags: linux, makefile

On my ubuntu 16.04 I just executed

```
cd src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.6.0.tgz
cd Python-3.6.0
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Can I delete src/Python-3.6.0 folder?

Comment: Well, If you once want to uninstall it, you may want to use `make uninstall`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@realtbo As you make installations using sudo command in LINUX, it is never suggested to delete those files. Any file which is in user is always meant to be kept alive. Deleting these files may cause your environment to break, which is not a good sign. Anyways these files occupy very low memory space. It is not a good coding practice to delete, but you can if you want to.

rm: Use this command to remove or delete a file in your directory.

rmdir: The rmdir command will delete an empty directory. To delete a directory and all of its contents recursively, use rm -r instead.

mkdir: The mkdir command will allow you to create directories. Example: "mkdir music" will create a directory called "music".

if rm or rmdir wont help, you can try `make -n install`

reference: Ubuntu